# Como criar uma lista de objetos?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, asp.net-core, objetos

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um projeto .NET Core Razor Pages e nele vou precisar criar e adicionar itens em uma lista... estes itens são strings e são extraídos de um XML.

Vou deixar uma parte do meu código a seguir, que é onde eu quero que os itens sejam adicionados a esta lista de objetos.

```
var descricao = "";
int i = 1;
while (result.vfp.row[i].men == "_MSYSMENU")
{
    descricao += result.vfp.row[i].des;
    i++;
}
```

Então, este `descricao` é oque seria a minha lista, e a cada vez que passasse por ali, adicionasse um item à minha lista.

Comment: E o que é esta lista? Como será usada? Quais requisitos dela? Dê mais detalhes.

Comment: Seguinte, preciso montar essa lista com os dados do XML, (que a partir das respostas que já tenho, estou montando) e usarei para montar um menu (`<nav>`). Agora vou precisar de usar a lista para criar cada opção do menu, no html @Maniero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for somente `String` você pode usar:

```
List<string> nomeDaLista = new List<string>();
nomeDaLista.add(result.vfp.row[i].des);
```

Aparentemente seu código possui algumas coisas meio estranhas.

O objeto `result` é oque? um `DataTable`?

Se sim, porque não usar assim:

```
List<string> nomeDalista = new List<string>();

DataTableReader reader = result.CreateDataReader();

if(reader.HasRows)
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
          if(reader["men"].ToString() == "_MSYSMENU")
             nomeDalista.Add(reader["des"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, mas `result` não é um DataTable, result é onde eu faço o `Deserialize` de um JSON, mas obrigado pela resposta, já consegui criar a lista